# Select every element that isn't a parent to any elements

Tags: javascript, css-filters

I am developing a game that glitches at some point through using the CSS `filter: invert(1);` property. However, when you use that property on `body`, it makes everything `position: absolute;`. This is not good because I need most elements to be `fixed`, and everything goes to a negative `top` and not visible. How can I effectively get all elements in a list that isn't a parent to any other elements, but included if it has text? Any answers or other stack overflow topics would be nice!
Here is some of my code:

```
// In a working loop called Repeat()
if(Glitch == 1) {


    document.querySelector(".ChangableStyles").innerHTML = "* {filter: invert(1)}"


} else  {

    document.querySelector(".ChangableStyles").innerHTML = ""

}
```

**Edit: Since all of you are asking, the `.ChangableStyles` tag is a style element. The filter on everything applies when I change the `innerHTML` of that style tag to valid CSS styles. I don't want to be rude, but I have the `.ChangableStyles` thing figured out. Thank you.**

Comment: Google would gave you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty . The rest is not clear.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I need it to select elements with text, too.

Comment: It's hard to know what you're trying to do here. Adding a string to innerHTML isn't going to effect styles.

Comment: @jmargolisvt The .changablestyles tag is a style element.

Comment: @jmargolisvt is correct, you're querying for *elements* that already have the `ChangeableStyles` class and setting the HTML *within those nodes* to the textual representation of a CSS rule. What you're doing in the above snippet isn't doing what you're expecting it to - you really should revisit your fundamental JavaScript concepts.

Comment: @esqew As I just said, there is only one `changeablestyles` class, and it's a style element. I'm doing it that way because some elements already have a style attribute, and I don't want to mess those up.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you already have a list of elements, but it's not clear how you're generating that list. I've gone ahead on the assumption you're wanting to "select" all elements in `<body></body>` that don't have any children.

You can use a combination of `Array.from()`, your pre-existing selection logic, and a `filter()` using `node.childElementCount === 0` to accomplish what you describe. However on higher-complexity DOMs this will be computationally expensive, so I would implore you to re-consider your design instead of opting for this route. To be clear, this will meet your requirement of selecting ANY `Node` in the DOM which has no child elements ("isn't a parent to any other elements"), which includes any `script`, `style` or other "user-invisible" nodes in the `body`.

```js
document.getElementById('get-elements-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log(Array.from(document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")).filter(function (node) {
    return node.childElementCount === 0;
  }));
});
```

```html
<div class="has-child-elements">
  <a href="#">This is a child element</a>
</div>
<div class="has-no-child-elements">
</div>
<div class="has-child-elements">
  <a href="#">This is also a child element</a>
</div>

<button id='get-elements-button'>Get elements with child elements &rarr;</button>
```